# Android: get image as we see in gallery instead of the Stratch Image

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, camera, gallery

In my app i am using this code to get Image from Gallery and Camera:

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     
    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {             
        Uri contentUri = data.getData();          
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };         
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);         
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);         
        cursor.moveToFirst();         
        imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);           
        //Bitmap croppedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        if(!(tempBitmap == null))
        {
            // here i am changing display to the tempBitmap
            photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), true);
            //photoBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, tempBitmap.getWidth(), tempBitmap.getHeight());
            takePhotoFromGallery = true;// edited
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } 
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==TAKE_PHOTO_CODE){
         final File file = getTempFile(this);         
         try {           
             tempBitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
             photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), true);
             takePhotoFromCamera = true;
             // do whatever you want with the bitmap (Resize, Rename, Add To Gallery, etc)         
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();         
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();         
        } 
    }
}
```

Now, all works fine. But i got Image as Stratch.

I thaught it is because this line:

```
photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), true);
```

here i am stratching the image width,height with display's width,height.

I want is the Image should be Dispaly as we can normaly show thew image in gallery. So how to make it possible ???

This is the image which i am snaping from the Camera:

[image]

And Now this is What i see in my Application:

[image]

Now Second image got little stratch. as because of that line code.

So what should i have to do to make is normal in its height and width ??
Thanks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ImageView and set scale type of image view to Center-Inside.